# Access 2007 - Query for some conditions

Tags: ms-access

I have connected the Access Database file via ODBC to MS SQL 05. I have a table with 5 data fields:

Example :

```
Date          Receipt No.   Customer No.   Item No.     Net Amount
----          -----------   ------------   --------     ----------
09/01/2016    M00001        111111         123          100
09/01/2016    M00001        111111         XXX          0
09/01/2016    M00002        222222         123          100
09/01/2016    M00002        222222         XXX          0
```

I want to get the data to sum up the total if the Item No. (same receipt no.) has a text called "XXX", and calculate the sum of Net Amount for 10%.

For above example, it will get the result for 10 dollars for receipt no. M00001.

Answer (score 0):

As you want sum of net amount per receipt no whose item no is 'XXX',you need to get those receipt no whose itemsno = 'XXX'
So following query will give this result
    SELECT  ReceiptNo FROM TableName WHERE ItemNo = "XXX"

Now, to find 10% of sum amount you have 2 options

1)Use innerjoin

```
 SELECT  B.ReceiptNo, SUM(A.NetAmount)/10 FROM TableName A  INNER JOIN
 (SELECT  ReceiptNo FROM TableName WHERE ItemNo = "XXX")B 
 ON A.ReceiptNo = B.ReceiptNo GROUP BY B.ReceiptNo
```

2) Use In Clause

```
 SELECT  ReceiptNo, SUM(A.NetAmount)/10 FROM TableName WHERE ReceiptNo
 IN (SELECT  ReceiptNo FROM TableName WHERE ItemNo = "XXX")
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you so much "KJV111", could you tell more how \ where to put this query in? Is it in the SQL View in the Query I make?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much "KJV111"!

Could you tell more how \ where to put this query in? Is it in the SQL View in the Query I make? – Patrick, I have this query on hand...

```
SELECT [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].Date, [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Receipt No_], [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Customer No_], [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Net Amount], [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Item No_]

FROM [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry]

GROUP BY [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].Date, [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Receipt No_], [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Customer No_], [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Net Amount], [dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].[Item No_]

HAVING ((([dbo_xxx$Trans_ Sales Entry].Date)>#7/31/2016#));
```